# Programming projects website

Tags: c#, programming-languages

Does anybody know of a website where they have a listing of interesting projects that one can do to gradually ramp up your skills, and stuff that is actually interesting. This could be language agnostic or language specific in which case I am looking for C#. A great example of this [diveintopython](http://www.diveintopython.org/)

Answer (score 7):

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/).

Answer (score 4):

Project Euler is good, but very mathematical - you'll spend as much time on the maths as on the programming. Definitely spend some time working on those questions, but once you reach your mathematical limit (I reached it fairly quickly, and I thought I was good at maths!) I'd recommend working on some simple games. If you still want a listing, here's one:

- Text-based adventure
- Tic-tac-toe
- Tetris
- Pacman
- Breakout
- Mario
- Half-life

Comment: Half-Life is a simple game? I have a feeling that the good folks at Valve Software would disagree.

Comment: @Justin: I put that on the end as a joke - I forgot my `<irony>` tags though :P

Answer (score 3):

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) is a popular choice.

I also like [CodingBat](http://codingbat.com/) (has sections for Java and Python, but you can take the problems and use whatever language you like). Its problems are less like puzzles and more like basic programming concept practice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, interesting depends on where your interests lie. diveintopython is more of a advanced book than a list of interesting projects that one can do.

If you like math, Project Euler is popular. But if you don't, like me, just look for a problem that you can solve, a tool that you could use personally. All practice can help ramp up your skills, doesn't matter what projects you work on.

Comment: I get your point on DiveIntoPython, what I just meant is that the examples used are very practical and are actually useful